# On the nearest integer to $\zeta^{(k)}(1-1/B),B \ge 2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Let $k \ge 1,B \ge 2$ integers and $\zeta^{(k)}(s)$
denote the $k$-th derivative of Riemann zeta function.
For real $x$, let $[x]$ denote the nearest integer to $x$.

Conjecture 1:  For all $n \ge 1,[\zeta^{(n)}(1/2)]= -2^{n+1} n!$

Conjecture 2:  For all $k \ge 1,B \ge 2$ we have $[\zeta^{(k)}(1-1/B)]= -B^{k+1}\cdot k!$ and $\zeta^{(k)}(1-1/B)$ is very close to integer.

sagemath code per request:

```
def zetania2(LK=10,prec=100,bb=[3,5]):
    """
    zeta^(k)(1-1/B), near to integers
    """
    import mpmath
    mpmath.mp.pretty=1
    mpmath.mp.dps=prec
    pre2=10
    for B in bb:
        l0=[]
        lerr=[]
        for k in range(1,LK+1):
            T=mpmath.zeta(1-1/mpmath.mpf(B),derivative=k)
            N=mpmath.nint(T)
            N2= -B**(k+1) * factorial(k)
            l0 += [N-N2]
        print(B,l0)
```

Comment: Could you please provide some numerical evidence?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN Added sagemath code. I believe you can run it in a browser.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN Can you check the conjectures with a CAS different from sage/mpmath? Answer claims they are false.

Comment: I'm not well versed in using such software. And to be honest, as your conjectures are disproven, I don't quite see the point of checking them.

Comment: @MarkSapir The questions are entirely different: one is true, one is false.

Answer (score 2):

Both conjectures are false. Suppose your conjectured identity holds for all $k\geq 1$ and some $B\geq 2$. It is known that
$$
f(s)=\zeta(s)-\frac{1}{s-1}
$$
is an entire function. Your identity for fixed $B$ implies, for instance, that $|f^{(k)}(1-1/B)|\leq 1$. By Taylor expansion, from this we get for all $s\in \mathbb C$ that
$$
|f(s)|=\left|\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{f^{(k)}(1-1/B)}{k!}(s-1+1/B)^k\right|\leq |f(1/B)|+e^{|s-1+1/B|}.
$$
The last bound cannot hold, because $f(-n)$ grows more than exponentially for odd integer $n\to+\infty$.

UPDATE: as for the numerical evidence, $k=41$ seems to be the least value of $k$ with
$$
|\zeta^{(k)}(1-1/B)+k!B^{k+1}|>1
$$
for $B=2,3,4$. This was computed using the function $\it{derivnum}$ in Pari/GP.

Comment: Thanks. I get experimental support for the conjectures, possibly due to a bug in the libraries I am using. What would be a small counterexample or set of counterexamples to check numerically?

Comment: The derivatives of $\zeta(s)$ at a point such as $1-1/B$ behaves in a complicated way. The first few may be dominated by the pole at $0$. So they are near integers if $B$ is an integer.  The Taylor series of $f(s)$ is not a good recipe to compute $f(-n)$.   Mathematica gives $\zeta^{(4)}(1-1/3)=-5831.99742689039619$ near an integer.  mpmath gives  -5831.9974268904026.  I do not think there is a bug here.

Comment: I believe the above proof is false: the inequality $|f^{(k)}(1-1/B)|\le1$ is implied by the conjecture only for $k$ odd. I believe that using Cauchy it should be easy to prove that the conjectures are both true, replacing integer part by nearest integer. Once this is done, one can ask how the difference behaves, both in sign (is it governed by the complex zeros?) and in magnitude (it tends very fast to $0$, at least experimentally).

Comment: @Henri Cohen, why is it only implied for $k$ odd? The $k$-th derivative of $(s-1)^{-1}$ at $s=1-1/B$ is precisely $k!(-1)^k(s-1)^{-k-1}=-k!(1/(1-s))^{k+1}=-k!B^{k+1}$, the parity of $k$ shouldn't matter, as far as I see.

Comment: @Henri Cohen, besides, even if it was true only for odd $k$, this would imply a similar exponential bound for $f(s)−f(2−2/B−s)$, which is once again false due to the same counterexample. I believe that the experimental data is a kind of the "law of small numbers" and the fact that $\zeta(s)$ grows "slightly" more than exponentially at $s=−n$ for large odd $n$ contributes to this

Comment: @joro, it was not a bug, you just needed to pick a large $k$ (see the update in the answer)

Comment: @Henri Cohen: joro does consider the nearest integer.

Comment: My bad. I had divided by $k!$ in my computations.

Comment: Many thanks for the counterexample! I can reproduce it with mpmath.