# Nearest integers to derivatives of zeta

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Closely related, but different from [this solved quesion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404779/on-the-nearest-integer-to-zetak1-1-b-b-ge-2)

Let $\zeta^{(k)}(s)$
denote the $k$-th derivative of Riemann zeta function.
For real $x$, let $[x]$ denote the nearest integer to $x$.

Conjecture 1:  For integer $B \ge 2$ we have
$[\zeta^{(1)}(1-1/B)]=[\zeta^{(1)}(1+1/B)]$

Conjecture 2:  Let $k=1$ or $k=2$.
Then $[\zeta^{(k)}(1-1/B)]= -B^{k+1}\cdot k!$

According to computations with mpmath and pari/gp, both hold up to 10^5
for integer $B$.

From the linked question, $k=41$ violates generalization of (2).

Comment: good old $41$ ...

Comment: @PietroMajer I don't get your comment. 41 is not counterexample according to my computations.

Comment: $41$  is also the first positive integer number $n$ that violates "$n^2+n+41$ is prime" :)

Comment: (I think both conjectures are true; it's just a matter of bounding a remainder in the Laurent expansion of $\zeta$ at $1$)